# Video Streaming through TCP

Tags: video, tcp, streaming

I need to stream video data which is stored on a server on to a video player on my browser. I can use a TCP connection to get a piece of the video file as a byte array.

How can I go about retrieving the video piece by piece using TCP while streaming the portion that is already retrieved on the video player.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the options VLC has for streaming (see videolan.org). You realy don't wat to implement a video streaming protocol by hand, not if you have other things you'd like to do with your life.

Answer (score 0):

Get a ready implementation of [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) or [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) (which is over UDP), for example. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you still want to write the code yourself - implement known protocols used for this task, don't create new ones.